SAP document extraction for Data engineering pipeline
I am trying to figure out a viable design to extract the documents (PDFs) from SAP document management service and store into Azure Blob.
I have scoured the internet to understand which service is used to connect to SAP DMS? I don't have access to SAP so that makes the task even more difficult.
Can somebody from SAP provide some pointers into which direction I should look at.
Basically, we should be able to extract the documents(PDFs) and then read the versions, deletions and process the changes into Blob.
We want to build the repo to put a GenAI app on top of it.
I have come across this CMIS library from Python but not sure if this is the correct way to do it.
https://chemistry.apache.org/python/docs/
https://help.sap.com/docs/document-management-service/sap-document-management-service/cmis-open-standard
